# CodeSign Error after changing Product Name

Tags: objective-c, ios4, code-signing, appstore-approval

I recently come across a hectic problem when App Store rejected my application saying that the App Name and the Product Name are not same. I followed the steps told by them to change the product name. But when I rebuilt the app, it gives me a codesigning error:

> Error : codesign failed with exit code 1

Any idea what the problem is here?

Comment: You should post the fix you found as an answer yourself, and then mark that answer as accepted. One advantage to this is that you will get the rep if a user upvotes your answer!

Comment: Thanks for this info :) I will surely follow this :)

Comment: Thanks for following up. I have edited both the question and the answer so that they only contain question and answer details respectively, and removed superfluous text per SO's established practices. Don't forget to accept your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that there where different names entered in the following configuration fields:

- Project -> Edit Active Target -> Properties Tab -> Field "Executable"
- Project -> Edit Active Target -> Build Tab -> Field "Product Name"
- info.plist (or *.plist) the field "executable file"

So make sure that these fields contain the same value.

The root of the problem that I renamed the executable file in the .plist file cause the initial name of the xcode project was not the name of the final product.

Comment: Some users don't look at time stamps prior to flagging, which accounts for 99.9% of my motivation when leaving that comment. Please ping me when you do accept this, so I can remove these comments.