# Stuck when changed the Product Name

Tags: objective-c, ios4, code-signing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CodeSign Error after changing Product Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330371/codesign-error-after-changing-product-name)

I have been stuck in a problem in which I changed my app product name and then I start getting the following error:

"codesign failed with exit code 1".

Everything was fine before this but I don't know why Xcode is doing mess now :(. Kindly help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at my post

[CodeSign Error after changing Product Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330371/codesign-error-after-changing-product-name/7330383#7330383)

Hope it will help you.

Regards,

Wasim.

Comment: Oh my God I cant even imagine that it would create a problem :o. Thanks a ton @Wasim! You are a Hero!

Comment: @Paul Don't forget to up vote/accept Wasim answer!